# How to easily switch between virtual machines in VMWare Fusion

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have two virtual machines open at the same time in VMWare Fusion. I often switch between OSX and the virtual machines. Switching from OSX to the last virtual machine I used is not too difficult. However switching from one virtual machine to the other is not as simple. I run the virtual machines maximized. In order to switch to the other virtual machine I have to use the menu and select it. If I'm using an OSX application then the menu isn't even showing. Is there some easy way to switch between the different virtual machines?

Comment: What are you doing? Might a shell command to the other VM work - or a remote desktop?

Comment: I just have multiple VMs open, just like having multiple windows open. The problem is I can't find a keyboard shortcut to switch between the VMs just like there are keyboard shortcuts to switch between windows.

Comment: You could report a bug to VMware, that the option *Enable Mac OS X Keyboard Shortcuts* doesn't work with the window switching shortcut (e.g. `Cmd-Backtick`)

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for. If I'm in a VM and I press that then it will switch to the other VM.

Comment: @OSXJedi So the Cmd-Backtick works for you in the virtual machines?

Comment: Yes, it works. But if I hold down Cmd I can't keep cycling through. I have to let go of it and then press it again. Not a big deal, it still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign keyboard shortcuts through *System Preferences* for the menu items named after your virtual machines.

[image]

[image]

This also works in full-screen mode, even though the "mini menu" doesn't show these shortcuts.

Comment: That works if I click on Window on the mini menu. If I'm inside a virtual machine and try to use those they don't work.

Comment: @OSX It worked for me with the assigned key combinations in both virtual machines, even though I forward key combinations with command to the VMs.

Comment: What do you mean by "forward key combinations."

Comment: @OSX Sorry, confused vmware and remote desktop there. My answer works for me though, pressing the keyboard shortcuts I assigned. What vmware fusion version are you using? Do you have the issue of this not working on all VMs?

Comment: Using 3.1.3. It doesn't matter which VM I'm using. I have to click on the mini menu at the top in order for the key combination to work.

Comment: @OSX I'm using 4.13 and also have to click on mine menu first. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I know this a 5 year old question but I just found it in a search for this same "issue" so it's out there as a source.

Don't know if this is something new with VMWare Fusion since the OP asked the question. But I found if I go to the setting for the VM (CMD-E) there is an option under 'Keyboard & Mouse' labeled 'Shortcut to trigger this virtual machine. I had a message at first saying it had been disabled in VMWare Fusion global settings, and had to go to those preferences first and enable it. Then I came back and set this option on the different VM's I was trying to switch between and now if I press the shortcut I set it switches to that VM.

Hope that helps others if they find this looking for the information.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+arrow works on Sierra 10.12.2 and Fusion 8.5.3. The preferences menu in the VMware Fusion dropdown contains a panel for keyboard and mouse, which includes <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> for switching between windows. It did not work for switching between a full screen (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) VM and any other VM window. It did work for switching between a partial-sized window and the preferences menu. It could be a bug.